# How to use RadixUI with React Hook Form's Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm unable to use Radix UI's select component with React Hook Form's Controller and don't understand why the following doesn't work in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-glitter-q8vmpj?file=/src/WrapperSelect.tsx). Any ideas?

For example, the [Radix UI documentation](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/select) shows passing value and onChange props to `<SelectPrimitive.Root>` as well as the ref to `<SelectPrimitive.Trigger>`

```
export const Select = React.forwardRef(
  ({ children, ...props }, forwardedRef) => {
    return (
      <SelectPrimitive.Root {...props}>
        <SelectPrimitive.Trigger ref={forwardedRef}>
          <SelectPrimitive.Value />
      ...
      </SelectPrimitive.Root>
```

How I implemented it:

```
const SelectItem = forwardRef(({ value, onValueChange }, forwardedRef) => {
  return (
    <Select.Root value={value} onValueChange={onValueChange}>
      <Select.Trigger
        ref={forwardedRef}
        className="text-md border-solid border-2 border-slate-500 px-2"
      >
     ...
    </Select.Root>
```

How I pass value and onChange in `WrapperSelect` using [RHF's Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)

```
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref, ...props } }) => (
      <SelectItem
        valueOnChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        forwardedRef={ref}
      />
    )}
   />
```

Comment: `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? Check the render method of `Controller`.`. This results in this warning though

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, also with Radio button and I found out that you need to use custom `<Select.Value>` component with `asChild` prop

```
<Select.Value asChild>
  <span>{props.value ?? "Select something..."}</span>
</Select.Value>
```

Here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sun-xwupmz?file=/src/atoms/SelectItem.tsx

Comment: Thanks this worked. Altough you probably want to show the label which you need to find from the collection via the props.value.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the prop `onValueChange` expects a callback function of the type `(value: string) => void` and field.onChange is of the type `ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>` which means `(event: changeEvent) => void`